# Creating item using SharePoint web services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I need to create an item in a SharePoint list using Lists.UpdateListItems web service.
I have created a batch method and populate it with these fields.

```
<Field Name="ContentType">Document</Field>
<Field Name="FileLeafRef">??????</Field>
<Field Name="Title">Doc1</Field>
<Field Name="LookupColumn"></Field>
```

I don't know how the FileLeafRef format looks like. when i write Doc1.txt for example, the service returns an error.

Any one has an idea.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileLeafRef must contain the full path to the document.

But keep in mind that creating new documents in a doclib using Lists.UpdateListItems is not possible ([citation needed] && as far as i know)